# Making a printout using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, button

How to make printout using C#. At the moment I would like to make printouts of text contents only. That is something similar to Notepad, but the print actions would be executed when a Form Button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to be able to print a short, simple text string, try something like this code:

```
private void printButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument doc = New PrintDocument();
    doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printPage);
    doc.Print();
}

private void printPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    string printText = myTextbox.Text;
    Font printFont = myTextbox.Font;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(printText, printFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.X, e.MarginBounds.Y);
}
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) for the `PrintDocument` class contains a more comprehensive sample that can be easily modified to print the text from your textbox instead from a file on disk.

Both sets of code will send the print job to your default printer, but you can modify them to show a print dialog box and allow the user to choose which printer to use, among other parameters.

Comment: Can I use this code snippet or extended version of this to print PDF files?

Comment: @Nips No, this prints text files. You need something that understands the PDF file format. Do a search; there are lots of questions about it already.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look into [`PrintDocument.Print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx) method?